# How to handle derived lists using Reactive Extensions

Tags: c#, reactiveui

Given a simple item with soft delete capabilities

```cs
public class Person : ReactiveObject
{
    [Reactive] public string Name { get; set; }
    [Reactive] public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

I need to handle the deleted updates and remove the items on the UI (while keeping them in the list).

When I attempt this, the deleted item is not filtered out of the derived list.

```cs
public class PeopleViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    public PeopleViewModel()
    {
        DeleteCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(DeletePerson);
        this.WhenAnyValue(vm => vm.People)
            .Subscribe(people => people
                .ToObservableChangeSet()
                .Filter(x => !x.IsDeleted)
                .ToCollection()
                .Select(x => new ObservableCollection<Person>(x))
                .ToPropertyEx(this, x => x.VisiblePerson));
    }

    private void DeletePerson(Person person)
    {
        person.IsDeleted = true;
    }

    ICommand DeleteCommand { get; }
    [Reactive] public ObservableCollection<Person> People { get; set;}
    public ObservableCollection<Person> VisiblePeople { [ObservableAsProperty] get;}
}
```

What is the correct way to create a derived list whereby when a property within the list changes, it triggers the ObservableChangeSet to update?

```
------------------------------------------
|  John Smith                   [delete] |
------------------------------------------
|  Jane Doe                     [delete] |
------------------------------------------
```

## Edit

I did get it working with the following, but this feels really dirty

```cs
this.WhenAnyValue(vm => vm.People)
            .Subscribe(people => people
                .ToObservableChangeSet()
                .AsObservableList()
                .Connect()
                .WhenPropertyChanged(x => x.Deleted)
                .Subscribe(_ => people
                    .ToObservableChangeSet()
                    .Filter(x => !x.Deleted)
                    .ToCollection()
                    .Select(x => x.ToList().AsReadOnly())
                    .DistinctUntilChanged()
                    .ToPropertyEx(this, x => x.VisiblePeople))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was hung up on the fact that the `.Bind(out)` wasn't somehow notifying the UI of the changes. Turns out that this is the correct approach that does everything needed for derived lists.

```cs
ctor()
{
    this.WhenAnyValue(vm => vm.People)
        .Subscribe(people => people
            .ToObservableChangeSet()
            .AutoRefresh(x => x.Deleted)
            .Filter(x => !x.Deleted)
            .Bind(out _visiblePeople)
            .Subscribe());
}

private ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Person> _visiblePeople;
public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Person> VisiblePeople => _visiblePeople;
```

Comment: You can use the `AutoRefresh()` operator and potentially forgo the first subscribe.